# Oracle SQL trigger - how to block queries/procedures that happen after the trigger is invoked

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I was asked to build a trigger that prevents the system from printing a document without a specific field provided. I have built a trigger to throw an error message, whenever such situation occurs and it works.

The problem is that after my trigger is invoked and the pop-up is closed, the system calls/executes other sql queries and PL/SQL procedures, which change the data in the row (they update a document number with an auto-incremented etc, etc.,  which should not happen for a document that was not printed yet). As a result it allows user to undertake actions on the document, that should be blocked (like removing), thus possibly spoiling the numbering of all docs generated subsequently. Having stated all that, my question is: how can I block the pile of all those updates that happen after my trigger is invoked and the pop-up is closed?

Thank you in advance

Best regards,
Przemek

Comment: What is "the system?"  This sounds like a validation process that needs to occur in the code in "the system."  The trigger knows nothing about what happens after it is done.

Comment: It's an ERP system used in my company, are you implying I have no control over that? Does it have to be built by the software provider?

Comment: It is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need a trigger to prevent printing. You need something to prevent printing, and someone for some reason decided that a trigger is the best solution for this. No, it the worst solution. A specific way to implement it better depends on your ERP.

Comment: It's the only one I have I guess. Any changes in the code on the software provider side are extra payable and there's no budget for that. So I have to figure out a way to do it as a local system admin

Comment: Yes, you need to manage that logic in your ERP system.  There is no way to do what you want in a trigger.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, if you want to block "the pile of all those updates", you could write separate triggers to block each of them if the specific field wasn't provided. But there's not a way to have a single trigger prevent a series of updates if the system ignores its errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable. Once you validate that a specific field is not present, update that flag to 1. Do an If Else check and then call the procedures accordingly.